# Save encryption key in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption

We are creating an application with WPF that will be used by our clients to do calculations. 
We need certain data in order to be able to do the calculations. This data should not be accessible by the clients. This data can be stored in an XML file.
We also want to be able to control who uses the application. We planed to do this via a license file that specifies how Long the application may be used. 
We wanted to encrypt the file with the data and with the license file so that the users cannot open them.

My problem is that I need to store the encryption key somewhere. 
When I hard code this key into the application it can be discovered via decompilation. 
Is it possible to save the encryption somewhere without the user being able to access this? Where could I save this key?
Do some libraries exist to achive this?

Answer (score 1):

Check [Rihino](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-licensing) licencing project.

Answer (score 1):

If all  data is on the client and nothing is validated from a server, there is always a way to hack your client application. You should instead make a service that does the calculations and the wpf application is just a thin client that access the server and within each request the client license is provided and validated if the client still has access to the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use obfuscation to protect your code from being reverse engineered. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977082(v=vs.107).aspx) from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can still store the key on a distant server / on a website.

Or you can move your whole method server-side using Litecode, [here is an open source project written by 'debug-hf' which will help you figuring out how to do so](https://github.com/debug-hf/LiteCode-Example).